# MVVM property not getting refreshed in View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following View Model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using DOSTreeListModule.DataAdapter;
using WebApi2.SpaceDBData;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm;
using Meijer.Merch.Shared.Infrastructure; 


namespace DOSTreeListModule.ViewModel
{
    public class DOSAdminProductHrcyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly IWebApiDataAdapter _webAPIDataAdapter;

        public DOSAdminProductHrcyViewModel()
    {
        this._webAPIDataAdapter = new DosAdminDataAdapter();
        //this.ProductList = new Task<List<Product>>(this.GetProductList());
        //OnPropertyChanged("ProductList");
    }

    public List<Product> prdLst;

    public List<Product> ProductList
    {
        get
        {
            GetProductList();
            return prdLst;
        }
        set
        {
            ProductList = value;
        }
    }



    private async void GetProductList()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Product> dbProductList = new List<Product>();
            var result = await _webAPIDataAdapter.GetProductHierarchy();
            foreach (Product prd in result)
            {
                dbProductList.Add(prd);
            }
            this.prdLst = dbProductList;
            //return dbProductList;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductList");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Following is the TreeListControl in my View in WPF using ProductList property that is getting populated above:

```
<dxg:TreeListControl Name ="treeList" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" 
                             ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ProductList.Result,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="300">            
            <dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
                <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="P_Hierarchy" Header="P_Hierarchy" />
                <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="COMBasis" Header="Compliance Basis" />
                <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="COMStandard" Header="Compliance Standard"/>
                <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="DOSBase" Header="DOS Standard Base" />
                <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="DOSStandard" Header="DOS Standard Promo" />
            </dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
            <dxg:TreeListControl.View>
                <dxg:TreeListView Name="treeListView1" 
                                  TreeDerivationMode="Selfreference" KeyFieldName="ID" ParentFieldName="KeyID"
                                  ShowExpandButtons="False" AllowCascadeUpdate="True"
                                  ShowTotalSummary="True"/>
            </dxg:TreeListControl.View>
        </dxg:TreeListControl>
```

Following is my View's code behind:

```
namespace DOSTreeListModule.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for DosAdminProductHierarchy.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class DosAdminProductHierarchy : UserControl
    {
        public DosAdminProductHierarchy(DOSAdminProductHrcyViewModel vm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            this.DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is my TreeList control is not getting populated. Though I am getting data (around 7000 rows) in GetProductList() method I am not seeing any data in front end. Please help.

Comment: What is this `NotifyTaskCompletion` Unless that class inherits IEnumerable, it is not going to populate the control

Comment: You substantively modified your question after my answer, which affected the potential correctness of the answer.  This is [considered an unacceptable edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts).

Comment: I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: The change that you suggested is not working hence I edited my answer here.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about; you can't do that.  It's a substantive change.  My suggestion was not part of your original question, and neither what you had originally nor what I suggested worked; given that, it doesn't affect your question either way, but if you *change* your question, that affects *my answer*.  That's why it's against the rules.

Comment: Nkosi based on your comment I have edited my GetProductList -please check

Comment: @SormitaChakraborty check updated answer.

Comment: What is your "root" element ? Your Window ?  
And don't you have an infinite loop problem ? If something is binded on your ProductList, on the first get you'll call GetProductList, that will raise OnPropertyChanged("ProductList"); so you will have a new get ProductList call, that will call GetProductList ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are binding to the wrong property.  Your `ItemsSource` should bind to your `ProductList` in the view model:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ProductList.Result,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

should be:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductList}"
```

`ItemsSource` is what items show in the tree.

Comment: It is not working, I added ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductList,Mode=TwoWay}", still it is not getting populated.

Answer (score 0):

First update the view model to a little more flexible

```
public class DOSAdminProductHrcyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private readonly IWebApiDataAdapter _webAPIDataAdapter;

    public DOSAdminProductHrcyViewModel() {
        this._webAPIDataAdapter = new DosAdminDataAdapter();
        ProductList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList {get; set;}

    public async Task GetProductListAsync() {
        try {
            var result = await _webAPIDataAdapter.GetProductHierarchy();
            ProductList = new ObservableCollection<Product>(result);
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductList");    
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the view (code behind)

```
public partial class DosAdminProductHierarchy : UserControl {
    DOSAdminProductHrcyViewMode viewModel;

    public DosAdminProductHierarchy(DOSAdminProductHrcyViewModel vm) {
        InitializeComponent();            
        this.viewModel = vm;
        this.DataContext = this.viewModel;
        this.Loaded += async delegate {
            await this.viewModel.GetProductListAsync();
        }      
    }
}
```

And finally in view (XAML) bind only to the collection

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductList}"
```

Comment: Yes, it is just not getting populated.

Answer (score 0):

From the information I have I'd try :

```
public List<Product> ProductList
    {
        get
        {
            GetProductList();
            return prdLst;
        }
        set
        {
            prdLst = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductList");
        }
    }

 private async void GetProductList()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Product> dbProductList = new List<Product>();
            var result = await _webAPIDataAdapter.GetProductHierarchy();
            foreach (Product prd in result)
            {
                dbProductList.Add(prd);
            }
            if(this.prdLst != dbProductList)
                this.ProductList = dbProductList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }



ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=YourWindowsName.DataContext, Path=ProductList,Mode=OneWay}"
```